# Empirical distribution learns w.r.t total variation distance

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, machine-learning, borel-measures

I am trying to prove or disprove that the empirical distribution can learn any continuous distribution w.r.t the total variation distance. The context is the one of statistical learning.
I am quite sure that the proposition is false, but I might likely be wrong. I have looked online and into some books, but I couldn't find a similar formulation for the problem, so if you know some literature  that would also be appreciated.

---

(edit: as pointed out in the comment, the distance I am defining here coincides with the total variation distance in this context.)

I am considering distributions on the real numbers and the set
$$ \mathcal F = \{ g \in \mathcal C^b(\mathbb R) \ \mid \ \lVert {g}\rVert_\infty \leq 1 \} $$
and the corresponding F-divergence
$$ d_\mathcal F (\mu \mid \nu ) = \sup_{g \in \mathcal F} \Big |  \int_\mathbb R g \ d\mu - \int_\mathbb R g\ d\nu \  \Big |  .$$

I need to prove (or negate) the following:

> For any $\mu$ continuous probability distribution, given i.i.d samples $X_1, \dots , X_n$ from $\mu$, prove that the empirical distribution $\tilde \mu _n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i} $ converges in probability to $\mu$ w.r.t $d_\mathcal F $, i.e.  $$ P( d_\mathcal F (\mu \mid \tilde \mu_n ) > \epsilon) \xrightarrow[ n \to \infty ]{} 0, \text{   } \ \forall \epsilon>0 $$

With $\delta_x$ I am denoting Dirac's delta.

##### Some more information and my considerations

It can be proved that convergence w.r.t to $d_\mathcal F$ is equivalent to convergence with respect to $$ \tilde d (\mu \mid \nu ) = \sup_{g \in \mathcal C^c(\mathbb R) \\ \lVert {g}\rVert_\infty \leq 1 } \Big |  \int_\mathbb R g \ d\mu - \int_\mathbb R g\ d\nu \  \Big |  .$$
This might be helpful in proving the proposition, since $\mathcal C^c(\mathbb R)$ is separable: the countable and dense subset could be used to take care of the $\sup$ I believe, but I don't exactly see how. Moreover, I don't see how am I supposed to use the density of $\mu$.

Despite Chebyshev's inequality/WLLN proves convergence for any single $g \in \mathcal F$, with rate indipendent from $g$
$$ P\Big (\Big |  \int_\mathbb R g \ d\mu - \int_\mathbb R g\ d\tilde \mu_n \  \Big | > \epsilon \Big ) \leq \frac{Var(g(X_1))}{\epsilon^2 n} \stackrel{g(X) \in [-1,1] \ P \ a.s. }{\leq} \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 n}  $$
it seems quite hard to me that such convergence can happen uniformly over $g$.

One could restrict the problem to the subset of functions in $\mathcal F$ s.t. $\mathbb E [g(X_1)] = 0 $ by taking the expected value inside the random variable, but that isn't much and I'm not even sure if that would be a good idea.

I have been thinking of using some trivial continuous distribution (such as the gaussian or uniform distributions) as a counterexample, but proving that converge doesn't happen in such case is still hard: my main problem is taking care of the $\sup$ inside the probability.

Maybe there's some known theorem which can be used and is going over my head: Glivenko-Cantelli guarantees that $\tilde \mu _n $ learns any probability distribution w.r.t to the divergence corresponding to the half-line's indicators, but I don't think that helps.

Comment: Isn't $d_{\mathcal F}$ the total variation distance (or a multiple thereof) ? If you were to consider measures on a compact interval, e.g. $[0,1]$ then $TV$ gives the same topology as Wasserstein, and the statement is true. I don't know the answer in the unbounded case.

Comment: @GabrielRomon that is true, $d_\mathcal F$ coincides with the total variation distance on continuous distributions (but I don't know whether it's equivalent or not for general measures). I will add that into the question, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is false: the empirical distribution does not learn all continuous distributions w.r.t. $d_{TV}$.

Some days ago I found a proof: it holds that
$$ d_{TV}(\mu \ || \ \nu) = \sup_{g \in \mathcal F} \big | \mathbb E_\mu [g] - \mathbb E_\nu [g] \big |, $$
where $\mathcal F$ is the set of measurable functions bounded by 1 (there could be a 2 factor depending on your definition of $d_{TV}$). Once one utilises this, the proof is trivial.

For a given $n\in \mathbb N$, for samples $X_1, \dots , X_n$ one can consider
$$ f_n(x) = 1 - \unicode{x1D7D9} _{\{X_1, \dots , X_n\}} $$
which is in $\mathcal F$ for any sample realisation. Since it is Borel a.e. 1 it is s.t. $$ \mathbb E_\mu [f_n] = 1$$ for any continuously distributed $\mu$. On the other side, $$\mathbb E_\mu [f_n] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f_n({X_i})  = 0 .$$ So $$ d_{TV}(\mu \ || \ {\tilde \mu_n}) = \sup_{g \in \mathcal F} \big | \mathbb E_\mu [g] - \mathbb E_{\tilde \mu_n} [g] \big | \geq  \big | \mathbb E_\mu [f_n] - \mathbb E_{\tilde \mu_n} [f_n] \big | = 1.$$
Since for any realisation of $X_1, \dots , X_n$ there is such an $f_n$,
we cannot have probability convergence to any continuously distributed $\mu$.

I couldn't initially think of such a proof since I was still thinking about continuous functions $f_n$ to disprove the convergence, but once one finds the $f_n$ above one also sees how to build a continuous one. Since the proof seems correct to me, I'll close the question.

Comment: According to [this paper, p. 1438](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~arb4/publications_files/DistributionEstimationConsistentInTotalVariationAndInTwoTypesOfInformationDivergenceIEEEIT.pdf) it holds that $d_{\textrm{TV}}(\mu,\mu_n)=1$.

Comment: @Snoop that totally makes sense, but I think that with the above definition it is equal to 2 (I have often seen $d_{TV}$ defined in an equivalent way which results in a divergence smaller of a factor $\frac{1}{2}$)